# Sorting a AS3 ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, air, sorting

I am designing an Air application that needs to store thousands of records in memory, and needs to sort them efficiently, by various keys.

I thought of using a `ByteArray`, since that would avoid all the overhead of normal AS3 objects, and would allow me to use memory more efficiently.

However, the challenge is how to sort the records inside the `ByteArray`. I have thought of two possibilities:

1- Implement quick-sort or heap-sort in AS3, and sort the array this way. However, I am not sure this will be performant enough. For example, ByteArrays do not have methods to copy chunks of memory around; it has to be done byte-by-byte.

2- Create an Air Native Extension (ANE) that takes the ByteArray and sorts it, using C. the drawback of this is that it will be harder to implement for all the platforms it needs to run on.

What would you recommend? Do you have any previous experience doing something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say use Array or Vector objects, there's a possibility to sort Arrays on whatever key you want via `sortOn()`, and Vectors via `sort()`, so you can achieve whatever behavior you need, as the latter accepts a function as its parameter, [check here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#sort%28%29). And I believe you won't get anywhere with ByteArrays, since what is actually done in sorting objects is sorting links in there, while a ByteArray will contain actual data.

Comment: The drawback there is that the actual objects would take much more space than storing the raw data in a ByteArray. I need to keep tens (maybe hundreds) of thousands of records in memory.

Comment: Well, create a class that will consist of only public variables, it will have minimal overhead. I expect you will lose a lot of time trying to make yourself a ByteArray and wrecking a quicksort over it, with a special function of retrieving a piece of data by index and setting it back. Actually, such a function will consist of traversing to calculated position then callind a `readObject()` to retrieve a record, then back, and each time (!) it will try a type coercion. I guess it'll be a LOT slower than `Vector.sort()`, for only a 8MB memory saving.

Comment: Yes, 8MB means that you have two places that store 4-byte links for 1M objects, one in the Vector, one elsewhere (say, in what's called "overhead", there's a link of type Class in each object). Compare that to 2-3 instances of your record class, a ByteArray, and a coercion call at each retrival operation. Also, I am not sure if data written in the ByteArray will equal the sum of fields' sizes, there might be some overhead info written in there, that signifies the object. Even if so, a single string in your records will get you royally screwed, as you'll be unable to quickly get index.

Comment: I agree. That is why I was thinking of writing an ANE and doing this critical part in C (this has to run on iPad and Windows). But, I really hate the idea of compiling the Windows ANE on my Mac using a Windows XP virtual machine on VirtualBox !!

Comment: Well, my ad vice is first try with Vectors, if you'll have performance issues, consider building an ANE. Note, should you make a "native merge sort" implementation over Vectors, your overhead will be another 4M, while with ByteArrays it'll certainly eat up all your memory. Note that transferring 4 bytes is by all means shorter than transferring a complete record, while checking conditionals is only 2 address lookups longer than checking values in raw data.

Comment: Thanks. If I had to write the sort myself, I would use heap-sort. It doesn't need too much memory, and guarantees good performance if my data should be more or less sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should never design anything that HAS to have hundreds of thousands of anything in the memory at once. Offload stuff while you don't need it. Do you know how much 100,000 is? Taking a single byte and multiplying by 100,000 gives you a MB. For every 1 byte of data in a record, you will generate 1MB of memory. Recording 100,000 ints takes 4MB.

If your records have 2 20 character strings (a first and last name), a String character is represented with 8 bytes, so you have just filled the memory with 640 MB of nothing more than first and last names. Most 'bad' computers have like, what... 2GB of memory? Good Job taking up 1/4 of that.  Even if you managed to truncate this down to ByteArray level with superhuman uber bitshifing, you're still talking about reducing data by a factor of 8. So now you have 80MB for just first and last names and no other data. You could survive on that- except I suspect your records have more data then 2 strings. 20 strings? You're eating 800MB of data.   Offload everything but 100 records at a time, and you're down to 640KB of memory for those names. And yes, you can load and offload while sorting.

Chunks of memory don't copy faster than bytes. It's all the same. The reasons Vectors of Objects are performant when switching is because they switch references/pointers/one single 32 bit/64 bit number instead of copying chunks of memory.

It's not clear what you're sorting. Bytes only go up to values of 256, so clearly you're using more bytes than 1 for each record. You want to evaluate each set of... like 2000+ bytes against each other set of 2000+ bytes? Like "Ah, last name is bytes 32-83, so extract those bytes, for every group of 4 bytes, bit shift them 0, 8, 16, 32 bits respectively, add them together, concatinate their integer values into a a String, do a comparison, now compare bytes 84-124 against the bytes in the next option,  now transfer bytes 0-2000 to location 443530-441530 and....... Do these records have variable length strings or arrays in them? Oh lord.

Flash is not the place to write in assembly!

Use objects and test the speed & memory consumption. If either makes you cry, use more conventional methods of reducing load; like offloading materials temporarily into text files. The ugliest you should be getting is avoiding objects by storing each individual property in a different Vector. Vector., etc and having the same index refer to one record across the board.